# I have problem in implementing a weak form in Freefem++

Tags: equation-solving, pde, freefem++

I have a system of partial differential equations (PDEs) that I've discretized in time using a specific scheme. Now, I want to discretize it in space using finite elements. However, I'm facing an issue: my last equation doesn't conform to the weak form. The weak formulation of my problem is as follows:

Let's denote our domain as Ω, and W and P as test functions from appropriate function spaces. Additionally, Μ^{k+1}, U^{k+1}, and R^{k+1} are our unknowns at time step k+1, and we have the values of all variables up to time step k.

Here's the weak formulation with all three equations:

```
<U^{k+1}, W> = -<∇Μ^{k+1}, W>
<Μ^{k+1}, P> = <R^{k+1}, P> + <∇U^{k+1}, ∇P>
R^{k+1} = ∫_Ω A(U^k) * U^{k+1} dΩ
```

However, the last equation doesn't adhere to the weak form. My goal is to incorporate it into the second equation in a form that satisfies the weak formulation.

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this in FreeFEM++. Specifically, I need to address the issue where the last equation doesn't fit the weak form, and I want to integrate it into the second equation while ensuring the overall problem remains consistent with the weak formulation.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I attempted to integrate the third equation into the second equation, but FreeFEM is encountering an error and is unable to solve the problem.